# VB.NET Editor - invoking View.ShowSmartTag on newly typed code without having to leave the current line and come back

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, editor

In C#, I can invoke View.ShowSmartTag (which I have bound to a hotkey) on a line as I am typing it. For example, if I type

```
var x = new Regex
```

I can immediately hit my hotkey, add the missing 'using System.Text.RegularExpressions', and continue typing.

In VB.NET, if I do the same thing

```
Dim x = new Regex()
```

I can't invoke the smart tag unless I leave the line and come back to it. This is annoying not only because of the extra keystrokes and time it takes, but also because it means I don't get intellisense on the function I am using until I do it.

Is there a way to make the VB.NET editor behave more like the C# editor in this case, and allow the use of smart tags on the line that I am currently typing?

Edit:
Perhaps a macro that automatically moves the cursor down, then back up, and then displays the smart tag?